How Scope works in Nest js
As per docs if a service is a request scope then the controller depends on it and will be request scope automatically.
Imagine the following dependency graph: CatsController <- CatsService <- CatsRepository. If CatsService is request-scoped (and the others are default singletons), the CatsController will become request-scoped as it is dependent on the injected service. The CatsRepository, which is not dependent, would remain singleton-scoped.
import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

export class CatsService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {}
}

so in the example, that I share CatsService injected REQUEST which is the request scope then CatsService service should be requested scrope automatically?

Your understanding is correct. REQUEST is an injection token for the custom provider of the request object, and is set as scope: Scope.REQUEST, meaning whatever it is injected into becomes REQUEST scoped
